# How to resolve'updates persistent or state variables while computing outputs, therefore it cannot be used in an algebraic loop....' error with Charts

Tags: matlab, loops, simulink, stateflow

I have a Model with 2 charts created with code. My first chart is a test simulation which go to a `TIMER EXPIRED` state when `TimerStatus = 1;`. The error occurs with my timer chart : 
[image]

When I try to simulate I get the error :

```
'ES_TestDS/Timer_principal' updates persistent or state variables while computing outputs, therefore it cannot be used in an algebraic loop. However, it is in a loop with the following blocks. For more information, see Algebraic Loops with MATLAB Function and Stateflow Blocks.
```

How can i fix this ? I read about Moore chart but i don't know how to convert mine into Moore chart.

Edit 1 : I have this warning in addition to the error :

```
If the inport 'ES_TestDS/Timer_principal/Start_Timer' of subsystem 'ES_TestDS/Timer_principal' involves direct feedback, then an algebraic loop exists, which Simulink cannot remove. Consider clearing the 'Minimize algebraic loop occurrences' parameter to avoid this warning.
```

Same for `Stop_Timer`

Edit : Maybe it can help if i show the connection between my timer and my chart

[image]

Comment: Sounds like there's an [algebraic loop](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/algebraic-loops.html) in the model that contains your state chart that Simulink can't solve because it contains a persistent or state variable.  You'll need to break the algebraic loop some how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a manual solution :

- Go to **Model Explorer** and set the **State Machine Type** to `Moore` for the Chart which cause the error

[image]

- Delete all `entry, during, exit ...` statements in your Chart

The problem is i still don't know how to set the State Machine Type with Matlab code if someone know

Edit : `cht.StateMachineType = 'Moore';`